# Are there any advantages to an inverted serial prototocol?

Tags: serial, design, protocol

Why would someone implement an inverted serial protocol?  Are there advantages in doing so?  One obvious disadvantage seems to be that an extra device needs to be included in a circuit if the receiving device can't handle an inverted signal.

Context: The Futaba/FrSky S.Bus protocol (commonly used in RC model receivers) uses an inverted UART signal, and almost all discussion about it is how to re-invert it so that common processors can receive the data.  Why did this protocol not simply use a "normal" non-inverted UART protocol?

[Why are hardware inverters so prevalent?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369688/why-are-hardware-inverters-so-prevalent) Seems to touch upon this but doesn't clearly explain (at least to me) the rationale for implementing an inverted serial protocol.

Comment: For interest: RS232 is negative true on the bus with logic 1 being -V (typically -12 to -15) and Logic 0 being +V (12 to 15V positive.).  ASs others note this allows / requires an inversion at TX and RX if +ve logic is used on board - eg TTL with +5 = logic high and 0V = logic low.  The  inverting driver & receiver are generally as easy or easier than a non inverting one - not quite the single transistor able to be used with ground as one level, but not overly complex. .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> One obvious disadvantage seems to be that an extra device needs to be
>   included in a circuit

But if the signal needs to be buffered the 'extra' device is necessary anyway, and may be easier to implement with inversion than without. A single transistor can both invert and level-shift the signal, while protecting sensitive inputs from nasty voltages and ESD that might be coupled through the cable and external connector. Do do the same without inversion you would need *two* extra transistors.

Another reason for an 'inverted' signal is if [open collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) drivers are used, since they generally pull down rather than up. This permits (in negative logic) a 'wired-OR' configuration  with several devices sharing the wire, possibly doing [half-duplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)#Half_duplex) bi-directional communication on a single wire.

So why do MCUs typically have non-inverted serial UART signals? [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels) specifies the line voltage as positive for '0' or 'space' and negative for '1' or 'mark' (ie. an 'inverted' signal), but line drivers and receivers invariably (re)invert the signal at the logic interface. So the UART signal has to be positive in order to make the RS232 line voltage negative.

S-BUS actually follows the same convention as Futaba's [PPM](https://sourceforge.net/p/arduinorclib/wiki/PPM%20Signal/) 'trainer' signal used to send analog servo position information from one transmitter to another via a cable. Hitec also uses an inverted PPM signal, but some other manufacturers such as JR and Spektrum use a positive PPM signal. Just to confuse matters even more, depending on the frequency band and manufacturer an FM radio control signal may be 'positive shift' or 'negative shift', and output either positive or negative PPM from the receiver (if it has a PPM port). So in the RC world there is no universal standard.

Answer (score 2):

If the line idles at LO, but LO is 0V then you can't tell whether or not the line is dead or active. But if the line idles at LO and LO is Vdd then you can tell if the line is active or dead.

of course...you could always make the line idle HI and have HI = Vdd.